# Python regular expression returns whole matched string but also a part of the whole string

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I´m scraping websites with scrapy and I do filter informations like time and day with regular expressions. I´m getting the whole string but also additional a part of the whole string returned. How can I exclude this part of the string to just get the whole one returned?

```
class posSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = ["https://posaunenchor-eibach.jimdofree.com/"]

def parse(self, response):
            zeitpattern = re.compile(r'\s((montag[s]?|dienstag[s]?|mittwoch[s]?|donnerstag[s]?|freitag[s]?|samstag[s]?|sonntag[s]?).*[0-2][0-9][.:][0-5][0-9].*[0-2][0-9][.:][0-5][0-9]\s*uhr?)', re.IGNORECASE)
            zeit = zeitpattern.findall(inhalt)
            print(zeit)
```

output is: `('dienstags von 20.00 Uhr bis 21.30 Uhr', 'dienstags')`

Why is 'dienstags' returned one more time alone?

Comment: What was the input string for the output example that you have shared

Comment: Use **non-capturing** groups if you do not mean to extract those submatches.

Comment: In Python' regex, parentheses are meant for group capture. If you want to use parentheses for grouping, you must use a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`

Comment: Non-capturing worked for me thank you!